# Sitecore 8.1 API Documentation Related to Users

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I'm looking for API documentation on how to interact with user accounts. For example, checking if a user exists, creating a user, updating a user, getting user properties.  I've been to doc.sitecore.net but I still can't seem to find any of this documented.  Is it documented and where can I find it? If it is not documented, what other resources can I access?

In 6.x versions, I see that some of the functionality I need is in Sitecore.Security.Accounts.  However, I don't know if this is still current or if there is a better method for 8.1 and future versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 6.x guidelines are still the most current, and as of 8.2, there has not been any major changes to that API, so the Security API Cookbook is still your best bet.

https://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Security%20API%20Cookbook.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, this part hasn't been changed since Sitecore 6.x, so you should be safe to use [this](https://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%207/Security%20API%20Cookbook.aspx) resource.